# Como puedo ordenar con mas de un criterio de ordenación para objetos?

Tags: java

Buenas, se como puedo ordenarlo con un  criterio de ordenación para objetos teniendo el siguiente codigo

```
    public class Estudiante  implements Comparable<Estudiante>{
        //Atributos:
        private String nombre;
        private int puntos;
        //Constructores:
        public Estudiante(String nom,int pts){
            this.nombre=nom;
            this.puntos=pts;
        }

        /**
         * @return the nombre
         */
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        /**
         * @return the puntos
         */
        public int getPuntos() {
            return puntos;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Estudiante o) {
            return getNombre().compareTo(o.getNombre());
        }


    }











 public class linkelist {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            LinkedList<Estudiante> lista = new LinkedList<Estudiante>();
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Barbara", 85));
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Xuan", 45));
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Alex", 51));
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Kaka", 52));
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Logi", 53));
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Loki", 54));
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Alexis", 56));
            lista.add(new Estudiante("Zuan", 57));
            Iterator<Estudiante> iterador = lista.listIterator();

            Collections.sort(lista);
            while (iterador.hasNext()) {
                Estudiante e = iterador.next();
                System.out.println(e.getNombre());
            }
        }
    }
```

Quiero ordenador por nombre y después por puntos

Comment: No muestra la lista ya Ordenada?

Comment: Muestra la lista ordenada por nombre, pero quiero hacerlo a igual nombre que ordene por puntos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobrescribir el método `compareTo` para hacer la comparación de dos atributos, teniendo en cuenta que Nombre será el que "pese" más.

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Estudiante o) {
        if(getNombre().compareTo(o.getNombre())==0)
            return Integer.compare(getPuntos(), o.getPuntos());
        else 
            return getNombre().compareTo(o.getNombre());
    }
```

O en una sola línea sería también empleando la `interface` [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
Collections.sort(lista,Comparator.comparing(Estudiante::getNombre).
                 thenComparing(Estudiante::getPuntos));
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarías pasarle un objeto Comparator que defina la lógica utilizando el método compare.

Ejemplo

```
private static void order(List<Estudiante> estudiantes) {

  Collections.sort(estudiantes, new Comparator() {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        String x1 = ((Estudiante) o1).getNombre();
        String x2 = ((Estudiante) o2).getNombre();
        int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

        if (sComp != 0) {
           return sComp;
        } else {
           Integer x1 = ((Estudiante) o1).getPuntos();
           Integer x2 = ((Estudiante) o2).getPuntos();
           return x1.compareTo(x2);
        }
   }});
}
```